# Color-changing text on timer? (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, timer, colors

I need to make an HTML script with two buttons and some text, where the first button activates a loop timer, cycling through different colours of the text; the other button interrupts the timer.

I've tried to writhe the program with no luck:

```
<button type="button" onclick="startCycle()">Start/Resume cycle</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopCycle()">Stop cycle</button>
<div id="title">Colormatic!</div>

It is currently
<p id="indicator"></p>

<script>

var timerId;
var color = 0;

var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
document.getElementById("title").style.color = colors;

document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = colors;

function startCycle() {
    timerId = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
}

function stopCycle() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = null;
}

function changeColor() {
    if(document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML == 'blue') {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = colors[1];
        document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = colors[1];
    } else if(document.getElementById("indicator"). == 'green') {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = colors[2];
        document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = colors[2];
    } else {
        document.getElementById("title").style.color = colors[0];
        document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML = colors[0];
    }
}

</script>
```

Here, the button "Start/Resume cycle" is supposed to execute function `startCycle()` and the button "Stop cycle" the function `stopCycle()`, which start and stop the timer respectiveley.

The timer executes function `changeColor` which was designed to see which colour the "indicator" paragraph was showing, therefore recolouring the "title" division to the next colour in the list.

I guess I could have detected the actual colour of the "title" division instead of creating a new paragraph. That and a whole bunch of stuff I could have improved.

I even bet that I have done many wrong things here.

Thanks in advance for sparing your time!

**UPDATE:** I finally got it to work. view full code here:

```
<button type="button" onclick="startCycle()">Start/Resume cycle</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopCycle()">Stop cycle</button>
<div id="title">Colormatic!</div>
It is currently
<span id="indicator">blue</span>

<script>

var timerId;

var ind = document.getElementById("indicator");
var tit = document.getElementById("title");
var color = ["red"]

function startCycle() {
    timerId = setInterval(changeColor, 500);
}

function stopCycle() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = null;
}

function changeColor() {
    if (ind.innerHTML == 'blue') {
        tit.style.color = 'green';
        ind.innerHTML = 'green';
    }

    else if (ind.innerHTML == "green") {
        tit.style.color = 'yellow';
        ind.innerHTML = "yellow";
    }

    else {
        tit.style.color = 'blue';
        ind.innerHTML = "blue";
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 31: `} else if(document.getElementById("indicator"). == 'green') {`

needs to be:

`} else if(document.getElementById("indicator").innerHTML == 'green') {`

It was just a typo. Use the console inside your browser's developer tools to catch compile time errors like that.